# Objective-c - Uploading image to server and two strings and reading the response back

Tags: php, objective-c, json, xcode

I spent the past 3 days of my life searching on internet how to upload an image to server using Objective-c with 2 strings and how to handle the JSON responses.

So in this app, you select a photo and then press the button to upload it to PHP server, the request also includes 2 strings which must be handle as well. The request is POST.

The problem is that instead of receiving messages like "success" or "crash" from my JSON, I receive something like: <6e6f5f72 65717565 7374>

**Objective-c code sample(URL is censored from security reasons).**

```
// Convert photo to string
            NSString *photoString = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

            // Crypt ID, photo and magic hashtag
            // Create NSData objects
            NSData *dataIDSession2PP = [IDSessionPP dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSData *dataPhotot2PP= [photoString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSData *dataMagic2PP = [magicString7 dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            // Get NSString from NSData object in Base64
            NSString *IDSessionEncode2PP = [dataIDSession2PP base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
            NSString *photoEncode2PP = [dataPhotot2PP base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
            NSString *magicEncode2PP = [dataMagic2PP base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

            // Prepare request for server
            NSURL *uploadPhotoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.***************.com/photo.php"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *uploadPhotoRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uploadPhotoURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
            [uploadPhotoRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
            NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
            [uploadPhotoRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            // Profile photo
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 90);
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image_data\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // User session ID
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"member\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString: IDSessionEncode2PP] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // Magic string
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"kkkkarondi\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString: magicEncode2PP] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // Close form
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // Set request body
            [uploadPhotoRequest setHTTPBody:body];

            // Get PHP server response
            NSURLSession *updateProfileSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
            NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [updateProfileSession dataTaskWithRequest:uploadPhotoRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *uploadPhotoData, NSURLResponse *uploadPhotoResponse, NSError *uploadPhotoError) {
                // Console
                NSLog(@"Server data: %@", uploadPhotoData);
                NSLog(@"Server repsonse: %@", uploadPhotoResponse);
                NSLog(@"Server error: %@", uploadPhotoError);

                // Check HTTP response
                NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)uploadPhotoResponse;
                if (HTTPResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                    // Valid status code
                    // Check if any errors
                    if (uploadPhotoError != nil) {
                        // Error found
                        // Show alert message
                        UIAlertController *alert =[ UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"App Name" message: @"We could not upload your photo, please try again." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                        UIAlertAction *OKButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                            // Do nothing
                        }];
                        [alert addAction: OKButton];
                        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                    } else {
                        // No errors
                        // Console
                        NSLog(@"No errors found");

                        // Convert data response to dictionary
                        NSDictionary *uploadPhotoDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:uploadPhotoData options:0 error:&uploadPhotoError];

                        NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", uploadPhotoDictionary);

                        // Handle messages
                        /*if () {
                            // Success

                        } else if () {
                            // Database

                        } else if () {
                            // Crash

                        } else if () {
                            // Upload failed

                        } else if () {
                            // Missing values

                        } else if () {
                            // Invalid member

                        } else {
                            // Unknown error
                        }*/


                    }
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong
                    // Show alert message
                    UIAlertController *alert =[ UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"App Name" message: @"Something went wrong while uploading your photo, please try again." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                    UIAlertAction *OKButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }];
                    [alert addAction: OKButton];
                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                    // Console
                    NSLog(@"Wrong status code: %ld", (long)HTTPResponse.statusCode);
                }
            }];

            // Send the request
            [dataTask resume];
```

**PHP code sample**

```
<?php

// some secret code goes here

if (isset($_POST['image_data'])) {
    // Get POST values
    $member_ID = base64_decode($_POST['member']);
    $member_ID = base64_decode($_POST['image_data']);
    $member_ID = md5(base64_decode($_POST['kkkarondi']));
} else {
    // No request
    echo "no_hashtag";
    exit();
}


// Handle various cases and echo messages


?>
```

So how can I handle in Objective-c the messages returned back by "echo"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: At iOS end you have written code for `multipart request` but at the server end, you have written simple `POST` method to accept the image(s) as `base64 encoded` string.  try `var_dump($_FILES);` in your PHP code. you might get a clue.

Comment: So you say that because the image sent will be encoded with base64, I should remove the part with multipart/form-data from iOS?

Comment: First try `var_dump($_FILES);` at PHP end, if you see its populated, you can get your file directly form `$_FILES` variable. Here the [document](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) which may help you understand the scenario.

Comment: I tried, it show the same thing. On iOS for NSLog(@"Server data: ") prints "Server data: <6e6f5f72 65717565 7374>"

Comment: And for NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", uploadPhotoDictionary); says "Dictionary: (null)". Also no error where showed in my iOS console. It seems that iOS doesn't handle the JSON.

Comment: put `var_dump($_FILES);die;` as first line of php, and see what it return.

Comment: This is what I got: Server data: <61727261 79283129 207b0a20 205b2269 6d616765 5f646174 61225d3d 3e0a2020 61727261 79283529 207b0a20 2020205b 226e616d 65225d3d 3e0a2020 20207374 72696e67 28342920 222e6a70 67220a20 2020205b 22747970 65225d3d 3e0a2020 20207374 72696e67 28323429 20226170 706c6963 6174696f 6e2f6f63 7465742d 73747265 616d220a 20202020 5b22746d 705f6e61 6d65225d 3d3e0a20 20202073 7472696e 67283134 2920222f 746d702f 70687058 66566769 4f220a20 2020205b 22657272 6f72225d 3d3e0a20 20202069 6e742830 290a2020 20205b22 73697a65 225d3d3e 0a202020 20696e74 28393733 33303129 0a20207d 0a7d0a>